# Scroll tbody rows by rows when append()

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, rows

I would like a table whose rows are scrollable but unfortunately the Scroll Table plugin does not allow for use with `append()` or [I did not succeed](http://jsfiddle.net/buBAU/6/). In addition, I would like to scroll rows after rows if `append()`. I  made a jsfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/buBAU/5/

```
$(function () {
    $(".Add").bind("click", Add);
    function Add() {
        var table = $(this).closest('table');
        var id_table = table.attr('id').substr(0,2);
        var t = $('#'+id_table+' >tbody >tr').length;
        if (t==8){$('#'+id_table+'bis > tfoot').css('display','none');}
        if (t<9){
            $("#"+id_table+"bis").find("tbody").append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td><input type='button' class='Delete' value='X'/></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' class='argument' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' class='less' value='-'/></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' class='note' value='0'/></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' class='more' value='+'/></td>" +
                "</tr>");
        }
    };
});
```

With : `tbody{overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 100px;}` doesn't work...

Any suggestions ? thank's

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood that at the beginning of the title tag can improve the post. As for me